# Test if local socket file exists (i.e. /tmp/mysql.sock)?

Tags: ruby, sockets

I'm trying to figure out if a socket *file* exists.

IRB

```
2.1.2 :001 > require 'socket'
 => true 
2.1.2 :002 > File.file? '/tmp/mysql.sock'
 => false
2.1.2 :003 > Socket.unix '/tmp/mysql.sock'
 => #<Socket:fd 9>
```

As you can see, the socket file is not a *regular* file, therefor Ruby returns false.

Any **other** way (then using Socket.unix) checking if the socket *file* exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to use the [`File.socket?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/File.html#method-c-socket-3F) method:

```
File.file?('/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock')
# => false

File.socket?('/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock')
# => true
```

Alternatively you can use the [`Pathname`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-socket-3F) class:

```
Pathname.new('/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock').socket?
# => true
```

Comment: Damn, that easy (never checked the API), makes me feel stupid, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a generic [`File.exist?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/File.html#method-c-exist-3F) method which checks if there is any type of file system entry (directory, file, symlink, sicket, device, whatever...) at the specified path.

You can use it like this:

```
File.exist?('/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock')
# => true
```

If you don't care about the type of file there, this is generally the best approach.